# Cобытия клавиатуры

Tags: c++, input, ввод

Как в с++ считать нажатия на клавиши клавиатуры? Желательно считывать ansi коды клавиш.

Comment: @Kopkan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    int key;
    while(true)
    {
        c= getch();
        key = static_cast<int>(c);
        if(c == 13) // клавиша Enter
          break;
    }

}
```

Comment: getch() - функция майкрософт, в стандарте ее, вроде бы, нет. И у майкрософт она deprecated. Никогда не пользовался: она и без консоли будет принимать сигналы с клавиатуры?

Answer (score 1):

Вам для этого будет необходимо использовать или функции операционной системы, или функции библиотек, которые оборачивают функции ОС, давая, таким образом, простоту и кросс-платформенность. Что именно Вам нужно?
Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть в сторону SDL (http://wiki.libsdl.org/Introduction) или SFML (http://www.sfml-dev.org/).

Минус в том, что большинство библиотек, дающих эти функции, помимо предоставляют еще много чего, и почти всегда это будет пушкой по воробьям. Если пушка уже заряжена и готова - это ничего, но если собирать и разбираться в ней - эффективность открытый вопрос.